# Magmi Configurable Products Importation

Tags: magento, magmi

In Magmi v0.7.17, I can't manage to import configurable products.

Here is an example of the csv I've got (just fields related to problem here):

http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/8871/csvq.jpg

- First of all, I need to put "_attribute_set" for the importation to work, otherwise I've got the error “cannot create product sku:xxx no attribute_set defined”. But in every online documentation and in the Dataflow Export this field is "attribute_set".
- When I run the importation (using the Configurable Item processor v1.3.6), only the simple products are created and I've got theses errors :

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'attribute_id' cannot be null - INSERT INTO `catalog_product_super_attribute`(`product_id`,`attribute_id`,`position`) VALUES (?,?,?)

None of the attributes and attributes set exist in database, I want it to be created on the fly. But is it possible ? or do I miss some fields ?

Thanks !

Comment: In the ImportExport Model you have to add the attributes before I think. but I don't know how the magmi works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it works now. After a little debugging in the plugin, I saw that the column "configurable_attributes" was empty. I move it at the beginning of the files (next to attribute_set) and it works fine. It's due to the fact that I didn't encapsulate my text with "" in csv, because Excel doesn't do it. So I modified my file with OpenOffice and let it at the end.

Suddenly attribute_set is working too.

Be sure to select "Magmi Magento Reindexer", otherwise the products won't appear in frontend.

Attributes and attribute sets have to be created in BackOffice before importation. Magmi can just create values of attribute.

Comment: I am having same problem . i used your solution but not working

Answer (score 0):

What is work for me is:

> ```
> 1. Check "configurable_attributes"
>    - All attribute are listed ?
>    - All attribute are correctly spelled?
> 2. Check same for all custom attribute on header row
> 3. Check attribute "Use To Create Configurable Product" value is set "Yes"
> ```

This Error Means you are having error with attribute and attribute set.