# Error in Magmi configurable product import with Configurable Item processor

Tags: mysql, magento, csv, magmi, configurable-product

I am trying to import in Magento using Magmi a set of configurable and simple products. I have followed all the necessary steps correctly (I guess) that are described here http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Configurable_Item_processor.

Here is a **test file** with data that I load in the importer https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17_fWYfYmSiXdLYp80P0kafPrFYzwzp7JHGNlHQTM0S4/edit?usp=sharing

**Test cases:**

1. Running the import **without** *Configurable Item processor* works just fine but does not create the link between the simple products and the configurable ones in backend (which makes perfect sense).
2. Running **with** *Configurable Item processor* with all the combinations of plugin options (*Perform simples/configurable link* y/n & *auto match simples skus before configurable* y/n) yields all the time the fallowing errors:

   1 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'attribute_id' cannot be null -

   2 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'attribute_id' cannot be null - ERROR ON RECORD #3

The error is triggered by this line of code

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_super_attribute` (`product_id`,`attribute_id`,`position`) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

that you can find in */plugins/base/itemprocessors/configurables/magmi_configurableprocessor.php:246*

I have searched for a solution and found this one http://blog.mdnsolutions.com/index.php/magmi-not-importing-configurable-products/ where actually the guy solved the issue by replacing that line above with:

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_super_attribute` (`product_id`,`attribute_id`,`position`) VALUES (:a,:b,:c)
```

It is not working.

There is also another question on this issue posted here [Magmi Configurable Products Importation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056424/magmi-configurable-products-importation) however the solution appears to be very "vague".

**Working with:**

Magento - 1.9.0.1

Magmi - 0.7.20

Configurable Item processor - 1.3.7a

OS is Ubuntu running PHP 5.3.10 & MySQL 5.5.34

Comment: have you defined a "configurable_attributes" column ?

Comment: Yes I did. You can see it in the demo upload file.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts based on my experience:

- Are any of your attributes mandatory? I suggest putting something into the size column for the configurable product.
- For visibility, I use numeric values. For configurable products it should be 4, for simple products it should be 1 (you don't want them to be visible individually, rather you want them to be visible within the configurable products).
- Finally, how are you creating your csv files? If just with excel, you may get problems with the encoding and how it separates fields. I run my csv files through openoffice calc to make the files UTF-8 and the text fields are properly handled.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the exact same problem. Simples work, but configurables don't even with the exact same information/etc.

As it would turn out if there is a wrong "configurable_attributes" named attribute with a simple it still goes.

Example

```
_attribute_set,type,configurable_attributes,size_option,color,
"Default",simple,"color,size","Small","Gold"
```

No error

```
_attribute_set,type,configurable_attributes,size_option,color,
"Default",configurable,"color,size","Small","Gold"
```

Error

Turns out "color,size" was not matching to actual attribute names.

Was "color,size_option".

Check your attributes